# Accept Value From Pipeline Powershell Function

Tags: powershell, scripting

I would like to create a script that tell the user whether or not PSRemoting is enabled on multiple remote machines. Here is what I have so far:

```
function Test-PSRemoting
{
   Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)] 
   [string[]] $ComputerName,

   [string] $Credential)

   $file = Read-Host "Enter file location for all error details: "

   try {
    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential { 1 } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Problem 
    If ($Problem){
    $result = 0}
   } catch {
    $result = 0}

   If ($result -eq 1){
   write-host "PSRemoting is enabled on: " $ComputerName
   } else {
   write-host "PSRemoting is not enabled/working on: " $ComputerName    
   $Problem | Out-File $file -Append}

}
```

The function works perfect if I only specify one computer:

```
Test-PSRemoting -ComputerName Server1 - Credentials Admin
```

However, I cannot get the function to work if I specify multiple computers:

```
Test-PSRemoting -ComputerName Server1, Server2 - Credentials Admin
Server1, Server2 | Test-PSRemoting -Credentials Admin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the Process{} block in this case (also answers your comment about why it was only checking Server2).

```
function test-ps
{
    param(
     [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
     [string[]] $CN
    )
    process{
        Write-Host $CN "h"
    }
}

'test1','test2' | test-ps
```

http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-function-input.html

Comment: OK, using the Process{} block `Server1, Server2 | test-psremoting -credentials Admin` works fine but now `test-psremoting -computername Server1, Server2 -credential Admin` isn't working....

Comment: @user2278281 `$Credential` shouldn't be a string..... it should be a credential object.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/koteshb/archive/2010/02/13/powershell-creating-a-pscredential-object.aspx

Comment: @Colyn1337 I tried using credential object and it broke script. I kept getting an error message "WinRM cannot complete the operation" on machines I know PSRemoting is enabled. I'll keep playing with it though

Comment: @robbp I would rather have `Server1, Server2 |  [command]` working than `[command] Server1, Server2` so we're all good.

Comment: @user2278281 another thing you can try is by using kerberos authentication with your invoke-command.  That's typically what I do.

Comment: @user2278281 Although you're happy with using the piped call, to address your initial comment you could add the foreach so your process block looks like this:
    process{
       foreach($C in $CN){
            Write-Host $C "h"
        }
    }
...Then it will work for both of the following:
`'test1','test2' | test-ps`
`test-ps -CN 'test1','test2'`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, comments below note key points.

```
function Test-PSRemoting
{

[CmdletBinding()]
param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)] 
        [string[]]$ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential = (Get-Credential),

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [String]$OutFile
    )

process
    {
        # Pass computer name along the pipeline to allow for more then one.
        $ComputerName | % `
        {
            $pcName = $_;

            $problem = $Null;

            try
            {
                $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcName -Credential $Credential { 1 } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable problem;

                if ($problem -eq $Null -and $result -eq 1)
                {
                    # Use Write-Verbose instead. Test-* commands are meant to return true/false.
                    # But additional status can be viewed by adding the -Verbose parameter to Test-PSRemoting. i.e. Test-PSRemoting -Verbose
                    Write-Verbose "PSRemoting is enabled on: $pcName";

                    return $True;
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose "PSRemoting is not enabled/working on: $pcName";

                    $problem | Out-File $OutFile -Append;

                    return $False;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return $False
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Key points are:

- Use of `$ComputerName |` to allow for `Test-PSRemoting -ComputerName Server1,Server2` usage by handling you conditional logic per computer name specified. Invoke-Command naturally handles multiple computer names but your `if` statements do not.
- Moved `$file` to `$OutFile` parameter instead of Read-Host and marked as mandatory parameter to force input. Leaving `Read-Host` in a `process { }` block would mean that the file path is requested multiple times if `Server1,Server2 | Test-PSRemoting` is used. Also has the advantage of being able to be passed as a parameter instead of manually typed each time.
- Moved verbose output to `Write-Verbose` instead of `Write-Host`. Test-* commands should return True/False instead of a string. Use `-Verbose` to see verbose output. Additionally you could change the `Write-Verbose "PSRemoting is not enabled/working on: $pcName";` line to a `Write-Warning` instead.